# Hazard function equality $T = \min(T_1, T_2, ..., T_n)$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, survival, hazard

Let $T_i, i = 1, ..., n$ be independent continuous random variables. Denote by $h_i(t)$ the corresponding hazard function of $T_i$. Let $T = \min(T_1, T_2, ..., T_n)$. Denote by $h_T(t)$ the corresponding hazard function of $T$. Prove the following equality:

$$h_T(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n h_i(t)$$

Comment: Add `self-study` tag and read https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any lifetime variable $U$, we have $-\frac d{dt}\ln S_U(t)=f_U(t)/S_U(t)=h_U(t)$.  Hence,
\begin{align}
h_T(t)
  &=-\frac d{dt}\ln S_T(t) 
\\&= -\frac d{dt}\ln (S_1(t)\dots S_n(t))
\\&= -\frac d{dt}(\ln S_1(t)  + \dots + \ln S_n(t))
\\&= -\frac d{dt}\ln S_1(t) -\dots -\frac d{dt} \ln S_n(t)
\\&= \sum_{i=1}^n h_i(t).
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

We take $X, Y$ independent and  $V = \text{min}(X,Y)$.
We note $S_X$ and $S_Y$ the survival functions of $X$ and $Y$.
The c.d.f of $V$ is given by

\begin{align*}
P(V \leq v) &= 1 - P(V > v) \\
&= 1 - S_X(v)S_Y(v)
\end{align*}

From the definition of the hazard function we have that the hazard function of $V$ is

$$
h_V(v) := \frac{f_V(v)}{S_V(v)}
$$

With $S_V(v) = S_X(v)S_Y(v)$ and $f_V(v)$ the density of $V$ which is given by

\begin{align*}
f_V(v)  &= \frac{d P(V \leq v)}{dv} \\
&= f_X(v)S_Y(v) + f_Y(v)S_X(v)
\end{align*}

Then we can rewrite $h_V(v)$ as

\begin{align*}
h_V(v) &= \frac{f_X(v)S_Y(v) + f_Y(v)S_X(v)}{S_X(v)S_Y(v)} \\
&= \frac{f_X(v)}{S_X(v)} + \frac{f_Y(v)}{S_Y(v)} \\
&= h_X(v) + h_Y(v)
\end{align*}

Generalizarion to sequences of independent random variables is straightforward